# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Approximate' and 'float'

Tags: python, oop

I'm getting the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Approximate' and 'float'` from the following lines of code (see below for entire script, probably unnecessary but might be helpful):

```
                x = receivers[i][0] - ax.xx
                y = receivers[i][1] - ay.xx
```

Where `ax` and `ay` are objects of the `Approximate` class. I know *why* it's throwing the error, but I'm not really sure what I've done wrong. Surprisingly, I can't find anything addressing this sort've situation on SO or elsewhere.

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 98, in <module>
    localize(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
  File "example.py", line 75, in localize
    x = receivers[i][0] - Approximate.xx
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Approximate' and 'float'
```

```
import math
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Approximate:

    xi: float;  dx: float
    xf: float;  n : float

    ei: float = 0.0
    ee: float = 0.0
    xx: float = 0.0

    stop: bool = False
    done: bool = False

    xs: float = None

    def step(self):

        if (self.ei < 0) or (self.ei > self.ee):    # Better solution

            self.ei = self.ee
            self.xs = self.xx

        if (self.stop):                                 # Increase accuracy

            if (self.i >= self.n):
                self.done = True
                self.xx = self.xs
                return

            self.xi = self.xs - self.dx
            self.xf = self.xs + self.dx

            self.xx = self.xi
            self.dx *= 0.1

            self.xi += self.dx
            self.xf -= self.dx

            self.stop = False

        else:

            self.xx += self.dx

            if (self.xx > self.xf):
                self.xx = self.xf
                self.stop = True

        yield 


def localize(ax, ay, ta, bx, by, tb, cx, cy, tc):
    
    ax = Approximate(1,1,1,1)
    ay = Approximate(1,1,1,1)

    receivers = [[ax, ay, ta],
                 [bx, by, tb],
                 [cx, cy, tc]]

    dt = []
    x = None
    y = None

    c = 299792458

    for step in ax.step():
        for step in ay.step():

            for i in range(3):
                
                x = receivers[i][0] - ax.xx
                y = receivers[i][1] - ay.xx

                a = math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y))
                dt[i] = a / c

            a = dt[0]

            for i in range(1, 3):
                if(a > dt[i]):
                    a = dt[i]

                for i in range(3):
                    dt[i] -= a

            ax.ee = 0.0
            ay.ee = 0.0

            for i in range(3):
                ax.ee += math.fabs(receivers[i][2] - d[i])
                ay.ee += math.fabs(receivers[i][2] - d[i])


localize(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
```

Comment: Can you post the full error / traceback?

Comment: Sure! See edit.

Comment: Do you mean to do `x = receivers[i][0].xx - ax.xx`? You are subtracting a float from the entire class, and the class does not implement the `__sub__()` method. @KeithMadison

Comment: What are you imagining would happen when you subtract something from an `Approximate`?  How would Python know how to implement this?  You'd need to define a `__sub__()` method on the class for this to make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly intend to subtract a float from the `Approximate` class, you need to implement a subtraction method - this is done with the `__sub__` method. Something like:

```py
class Approximate:
    # Other methods remain unchanged.

    def __sub__(self, other):
        # code here
```

*Or*, try `x = receivers[i][0].xx - ax.xx` (if that's what you mean).